# The trait bound `T: std::fmt::Display` is not satisfied

Tags: rust

I am writing a basic binary tree structure and I want to display a node. It seems that Rust has trouble displaying a generic type, and I get this error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `T: std::fmt::Display` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:55:60
   |
55 |         write!(f, "Node data: {} left: {:?}, right: {:?}", self.data, self.left, self.right);
   |                                                            ^^^^^^^^^ trait `T: std::fmt::Display` not satisfied
   |
   = help: consider adding a `where T: std::fmt::Display` bound
   = note: required by `std::fmt::Display::fmt`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `T: std::fmt::Display` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:62:60
   |
62 |         write!(f, "Node data: {} left: {:?}, right: {:?}", self.data, self.left, self.right);
   |                                                            ^^^^^^^^^ trait `T: std::fmt::Display` not satisfied
   |
   = help: consider adding a `where T: std::fmt::Display` bound
   = note: required by `std::fmt::Display::fmt`
```

Here's the full code, including the iterators

```
struct Node<T> {
    data: T,
    left: Option<Box<Node<T>>>,
    right: Option<Box<Node<T>>>,
}

struct NodeIterator<T> {
    nodes: Vec<Node<T>>,
}

struct Tree<T> {
    root: Option<Node<T>>,
}

impl<T> Node<T> {
    pub fn new(value: Option<T>,
               left: Option<Box<Node<T>>>,
               right: Option<Box<Node<T>>>)
               -> Node<T> {
        Node {
            data: value.unwrap(),
            left: left,
            right: right,
        }
    }

    pub fn insert(&mut self, value: T) {
        println!("Node insert");
        match self.left {
            Some(ref mut l) => {
                match self.right {
                    Some(ref mut r) => {
                        r.insert(value);
                    } 
                    None => {
                        self.right = Some(Box::new(Node::new(Some(value), None, None)));
                    }
                }
            }
            None => {
                self.left = Some(Box::new(Node::new(Some(value), None, None)));
            }
        }
    }
}

impl<T> std::fmt::Display for Node<T> {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter) -> std::fmt::Result {
        write!(f,
               "Node data: {} left: {:?}, right: {:?}",
               self.data,
               self.left,
               self.right);
    }
}

impl<T> std::fmt::Debug for Node<T> {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter) -> std::fmt::Result {
        write!(f,
               "Node data: {} left: {:?}, right: {:?}",
               self.data,
               self.left,
               self.right);
    }
}

impl<T> Iterator for NodeIterator<T> {
    type Item = Node<T>;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Node<T>> {
        if self.nodes.len() == 0 {
            None
        } else {
            let current: Option<Node<T>> = self.nodes.pop();
            for it in current.iter() {
                for n in it.left.iter() {
                    self.nodes.push(**n);
                }
                for n in it.right.iter() {
                    self.nodes.push(**n);
                }
            }
            return current;
        }
    }
}

impl<T> Tree<T> {
    pub fn new() -> Tree<T> {
        Tree { root: None }
    }

    pub fn insert(&mut self, value: T) {
        match self.root {
            Some(ref mut n) => {
                println!("Root is not empty, insert in node");
                n.insert(value);
            }
            None => {
                println!("Root is empty");
                self.root = Some(Node::new(Some(value), None, None));
            }
        }
    }

    fn iter(&self) -> NodeIterator<T> {
        NodeIterator { nodes: vec![self.root.unwrap()] }
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");

    let mut tree: Tree<i32> = Tree::new();
    tree.insert(42);
    tree.insert(43);

    for it in tree.iter() {
        println!("{}", it);
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to supply the `where T: std::fmt::Display` type constraint to your types all the way down. That said, there are quite a few other issues with your code. The obvious one is that the `write!` lines end in a semi colon and so those methods don't return the result from the `write!` calls. You're also going to hit ownership issues and so you'll need to either `#[derive(Clone)]`, `clone()` and `+ std::clone::Clone` the type constraints in all of the places that happens. Containers like this aren't trivial in Rust and require a deep understanding of the type system to pull off.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is a [minimal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) version of this issue:

```
struct Bob<T>(T);

impl<T> std::fmt::Display for Bob<T> {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter) -> std::fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "Bob: {}", self.0)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let x = Bob(4);
    println!("{}", x);
}
```

---

Let's take a look at our `fmt` function:

```
fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter) -> std::fmt::Result {
    write!(f, "Bob: {}", self.0)
}
```

We can rewrite it as follows for better clarity:

```
fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter) -> std::fmt::Result {
    write!(f, "Bob: ")?;
    std::fmt::Display::fmt(&self.0, f)
}
```

Calling one of the formatting macros (`write!`, `format!`, `println!`, etc.) with double brackets in quotes, `"{}"`, says to call the `fmt` function from the `Display` trait for that argument (`self.0` in this case).

The problem is that we have some generic type `T`, so the compiler has no idea whether `Display` is implemented for it or not.

There are two ways to fix this.

First, we could add the constraint `T: std::fmt::Display` to our implementation of `Display` for `Bob`. This will let us use the struct with non-`Display` types, but `Display` will only be implemented when we use it with `Display` types.

That fix looks like this:

```
impl<T: std::fmt::Display> std::fmt::Display for Bob<T> {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter) -> std::fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "Bob: {}", self.0)
    }
}
```

Second, we could add that constraint to the struct definition, like this:

```
struct Bob<T: std::fmt::Display>(T);
```

This will mean that `Bob` is only generic with regards to types that are `Display`. It is more limiting and restricts the flexibility of `Bob`, but there may be cases where that is desired.

---

There are other traits similar to `Display` that can be called by putting different tokens in the brackets. The full list can be found in the [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/index.html), but, for example, we could use the `Debug` trait with

```
write!(f, "Bob: {:?}", self.0)
```

only then we would need to be sure that `T` is `std::fmt::Debug`.

Comment: Is it the same fix for `std::fmt::Debug`? rustc is also giving me the error E0277

Comment: Yes. It's the same fix any time you get error 0277.

Comment: `impl<T: std::fmt::Debug> std::fmt::Debug for Node<T>` doesn't seems to be working. `error[E0277]: the trait bound 'T: std::fmt::Display' is not satisfied`

Comment: @Bl4ckb0ne You likely need both. I prefer a `where` clause in this instance: `...for Node<T> where T: std::fmt::Debug + std::fmt::Display`.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead so I only need 1 fmt for both `Debug` and `Display` ?

Comment: @Bl4ckb0ne In your `Debug` implementation, you still call out to `self.data`'s `Display` implementation. So, for what you have, you'd need `impl<T: std::fmt::Display> std::fmt::Debug for Node<T>`. I have tried to make this more clear in my answer.