# How to cast generic T to String?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to print a custom type:

```
struct Node<T> {
    prev: Option<Box<Node<T>>>,
    element: T,
    next: Option<Box<Node<T>>>,
}
```

Now, the problem:

```
print!(
    "{0} -> {1}",
    String::from(node.element),
    String::from(node.next)
);
```

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `std::string::String: std::convert::From<T>` is not satisfied
  --> src/lib.rs:10:9
   |
10 |         String::from(node.element),
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::convert::From<T>` is not implemented for `std::string::String`
   |
   = help: consider adding a `where std::string::String: std::convert::From<T>` bound
   = note: required by `std::convert::From::from`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `std::string::String: std::convert::From<std::option::Option<std::boxed::Box<Node<T>>>>` is not satisfied
  --> src/lib.rs:11:9
   |
11 |         String::from(node.next)
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::convert::From<std::option::Option<std::boxed::Box<Node<T>>>>` is not implemented for `std::string::String`
   |
   = help: the following implementations were found:
             <std::string::String as std::convert::From<&'a str>>
             <std::string::String as std::convert::From<std::borrow::Cow<'a, str>>>
             <std::string::String as std::convert::From<std::boxed::Box<str>>>
   = note: required by `std::convert::From::from`
```

How to cast `node.element` to `String` and `Option<Box<Node<T>>>` to `String`?

Comment: Can you explain what you find difficult about the error message? What about the help text suggested in the error message?

Comment: That being said, using `From` for outputting things is kinda wasteful - `from` uses the argument by value, so you can't use it afterwards unless it's `Copy`. You want either `Debug` or `Display` (the former is derivable, btw).

Answer (score 3):

As the compiler tells you:

> consider adding a `where std::string::String: std::convert::From<T>` bound

```
fn example<T>(node: Node<T>)
where
    String: From<T>,
{
    // ...
}
```

This won't work for `String: From<Option<Node<T>>>` because there's no such implementation.

---

If you want to *format* your struct, you will want to require an implementation of `Display` instead. There's no reason to convert a value into a `String` just for the purposes of displaying it:

```
fn example<T>(node: Node<T>)
where
    T: std::fmt::Display
{
    // ...
}
```

Again, this doesn't work in your bigger case because neither `Node<T>` or `Option<T>` implement `Display`.

See also:

- [Should I implement Display or ToString to render a type as a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27769681/155423)
- [The trait bound `T: std::fmt::Display` is not satisfied](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40601780/155423)

You might want something like

```
fn example<T>(mut node: Node<T>)
where
    T: std::fmt::Display,
{
    print!("{}", node.element);
    while let Some(n) = node.next {
        print!(" -> {}", n.element);
        node = *n;
    }
}
```

or

```
fn example<T>(mut node: &Node<T>)
where
    T: std::fmt::Display,
{
    print!("{}", node.element);
    while let Some(n) = &node.next {
        print!(" -> {}", n.element);
        node = &n;
    }
}
```

Or even to implement `Display` / `Debug` yourself using the same code.

You should also read [Learning Rust With Entirely Too Many Linked Lists](https://cglab.ca/~abeinges/blah/too-many-lists/book/README.html). You are attempting to create a doubly-linked list which is not possible in safe Rust.